# Flash - is there free software to work with?

Tags: flash

I'd like to know how to start creating something in flash.
I wish I could create some flash games as I played them in my childhood :)
Give me some tutorials and nice resources.
And another important question - is there any good free software to work with flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been a discussion on ActionsScript compilers:

[Flash Compiler/Interpreter Optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690911/flash-compiler-interpreter-optimizations)

However, Flash is a dying technology.  I'd not spend my time learning it and rather, I'd be looking into HTML5 and related technologies, which are more smart-phone and tablet friendly.

Comment: but it is a good opportunity to earn something on flash games or rather just create something for android/ios or html5 web games?

Answer (score 0):

You could try FlashDevelop, see http://www.flashdevelop.org/